# ST_Contains and ST_Intersection in PostGIS can not get the right result

Tags: postgis

I have two polygons n1 and n2, both are valid geometries.

[image]

I want to test the functions `st_contains` and `st_intersection` in PostGIS. I imported n1 and n2 into postgis, then I execute the following SQL:

```
select  st_contains(n1.geom,st_intersection(n1.geom,n2.geom)) as contains_,
        st_within(st_intersection(n1.geom,n2.geom),n1.geom) as within_
 from n1,n2
```

I think the both results should be ***True***,but it is ***False***. In my opinion, the  intersection of n1 and n2 should be inside n1 or n2. So what's wrong with my test?

[image]

Comment: PostGIS interpolates new vertices along the vector of the respective edge, using standardized vector algebraic algorithms; with the inherent inaccuracy/error of floating point operations, a vertice is unlikely to reside on a functionally defined line vector when it get's tested again. or in other words; 15 decimal places leave plenty of room for misalignments when the data type cannot guarantee consistent numbers...you cannot blame PostGIS for that.

Comment: If you could insert a vertex or node, in each geometry for each intersection of their boundaries (I don't know how to do it), I would think that that problem can be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ThingumaBob gave you the explanation.

To illustrate or compensate for this, you can make a negative buffer on the result of st_intersection.

```
select  st_contains(n1.geometry,st_buffer(st_intersection(n1.geometry,n2.geometry),-0.000001)) as contains_,
    st_within(st_intersection(n1.geometry,n2.geometry),n1.geometry) as within_
from n1,n2
```

The sql request will return True to you.